# Javascript RegEx Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Suppose I have this:

```
$('ul.child').slideUp('slow');
```

What would be the regex to find `'ul.child'` and `'slow'` (including quotes) in the above expression.

Comment: Do you try to parse JavaScript code with regular expressions?

Comment: @Gumbo: yes but here I think it is not about any language, it is about finding what is in-between the single quotes.

Comment: Guys your suggested regex selects `'ul.child').slideUp('slow'` that all, should not select `).slideUp(` part. It should only select what is in-between the single quotes.

Comment: Give the question a meaningful title

Comment: @Shermozle: You are perfectionist, what should be the title and would you consider your voting if i change the title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var a = "$('ul.child').slideUp('slow');";  
var matches = a.match(/'[\w.]*'/g));
// matches[0] = 'ul.child'
// matches[1] = 'slow'
```

`g` is a modifier and matches every occurrence of the expression.

If you want to match more expressions, like `ul li`, `ul + li` or `ul, li`, you have to put those additional characters into the character class.

---

Update 1 was not helping.

---

**Update2:**

You had a slight mistake in one of your regex. Change this:

```
// single quote string
the_code = the_code.replace(/('.+')/g,'<span class="code_string">$1</span>');
```

to

```
// single quote string
the_code = the_code.replace(/('.+?')/g,'<span class="code_string">$1</span>')
```

You have to make it non-greedy (with the `?`) in order to **not** match to the last occurrence of a `'`, but to the next one.

See here: http://jsbin.com/azovo3/4

If you want to match single and double quote, chage it to this:

```
the_code = the_code.replace(/(('|").+?("|'))/g,'<span class="code_string">$1</span>');
```

Comment: I want to use regex something like this: `the_code = the_code.replace(/^[^']*?('[\w.]*')*$/,'<span class="comment">$1</span>');`. How do i modify my code as per your regex?

Comment: Basically i want to replace not match.

Comment: @Sarfraz: It would be very helpful if you show an example of with which strings you start from and what do you want to have as result.

Comment: @Felix: please see this: http://jsbin.com/azovo3/edit . You can edit your part where your name is written. If you preview that, you would see the problem at the line `$('ul.child').slideUp('slow');`, it makes whole expression red.

Comment: @Sarfraz: I edit it, I don't know whether it looks right, but the HTML is how it should be like ;) But I noticed that `$(` is outside of the code string `span`.

Comment: @Sarfraz: Well it is http://jsbin.com/azovo3/3/edit. But I assume you want to have the stuff inside the quotes red and all the other stuff blue right?

Comment: @Felix: even your edit shows the same problem, whole expression red. It should red only what is inside quotes.

Comment: with your updated regex, it doesn't select other strings. You can check that out by editing in jsbin. Thanks

Comment: @Sarfraz: It is not totally red , the quotes are green and only `slideUp` is red in my case. But you chose the wrong thing for substitution. You should substitute with `<span class="code_string">$1</span>` not `class=comment`. And for some reason there is already a `<span class="code_string">` around it, that is why it is red. I guess this is due to some previous substitution.

Comment: @Felix: One last thing though, how about coloring red anything coming in double quotes like you did for single quotes? Thanks

Comment: @Sarfraz: Actually this should be done by the last piece of code in my answer... Just replace your the regex for your single quotes with this. But you have to put the regex for the comments **after** that for the quote otherwise it will be messed up.

Comment: @Felix: I tried that but at some places, it is adding `"comment">` on the output. What could be wrong there? This is the final correction to be made for what I have been trying to do. Thanks

Comment: @Felix: Fixed done, thanks, i moved all comments regex below :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/('[^']*?')/
```

e.g.

```
var test = "$('ul.child').slideUp('slow');";
matches = test.match(/('[^']*?')/g);
```

That's the closest I could get in a hurry. Hope this helps.
*When I come back, I'll tackle this*

Comment: It selects `'ul.child').slideUp('slow'` that all, should not select `).slideUp(` part

Comment: What happens if you put bracket as I did?

Comment: please see this: http://jsbin.com/azovo3/edit . If you preview that, you would see the problem at the line $('ul.child').slideUp('slow');, it makes whole expression red.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you possibly will need that but that will do the trick.

```
var str = "$('ul.child').slideUp('slow');";
var matches = str.match(/\$\((.+)\)\.slideUp\((.+)\);/);
console.log(matches[1]); // 'ul.child' (with quotes)
console.log(matches[2]); // 'slow' (with quotes)
```

And yes, `matches` indices are correct, `matches[0]` contains the whole matched part, while indices >= 1 contain matched groups

Comment: that's very specific involving the slideup keyword.

Comment: Yes it is, but the question didn't say it should be more generic.

Comment: please see this: http://jsbin.com/azovo3/edit . If you preview that, you would see the problem at the line $('ul.child').slideUp('slow');, it makes whole expression red.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[^']*?('[\w\.]*')*$/
```

I did this on the following regex tester page and it found both of your strings:

[RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/)

You can use capture groups to get the matches easily.  The expression goes:

1. Anything not a single quote, lazy match all `[^']*?`
2. Capture anything starting with a quote, containing any number of word characters or periods, followed by a single quote greedy match all `('[\w\.]*')*`

Is that close to what you want?

Comment: The dot `.` does not have to be escaped in character classes.

Comment: please see this: http://jsbin.com/azovo3/edit . If you preview that, you would see the problem at the line $('ul.child').slideUp('slow');, it makes whole expression red.

Comment: yeah, you gotta pull the capture group out.  check out the answer to this question.  he runs regex.exec and a matches array gets returned.  you pull the matches out by position and test the size, etc to get at them.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex

Comment: Thanks for that link. I am not that good at regex, things posted on that link are difficult for me :(